# show div elements on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div populated from database. i was trying to hide some items on my div and display them `on hover` something like this:
[image]

i made my div `display:none` and when hover i tried this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".maindiv").hover(function () {
        $(this).children().css("display","block");
    });
</script>
```

the same code but with child div id:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".maindiv").hover(function () {
        $("#more").css("display","block");
    });
</script><br/>
```

html code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="brandsRepeater" runat="server" DataSourceID="BrandsSqlDataSource">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="class1" style="width: 212px; text-align: center; margin-top: 15px; font-size: 10px; font-family: Tahoma; padding-bottom: 0px;" >
                        <div class="main" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                            <img src="path/<%# Eval("Img") %>" />
                            <div style="vertical-align: bottom; font-size: 10px; font-family: Tahoma;color:#1872AB;display:none;" id="more">
                                <a href="path/<%# Eval("Img") %>" rel="myimg" title="<%# Eval("DESCR") %>" style="color:#1872AB;">ABOUT</a>| <a href="mypage.aspx" style="color:#1872AB;">SHOP</a> | <a href="http://example.ca" target="_blank" style="color:#1872AB;">WEBSITE</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

but it seems that my code not working
any ideas?
thank you

Comment: provide relevant HTML markup in question. BTW, you could use only CSS for that behaviour

Comment: your question doesnt seems to be complete .. please improve it so that others can get more idea .. give in more code that u ve tried

Comment: Echoing the other comments. You best bet would be to put up a http://jsfiddle.net/ with it not working. You'll almost certainly get a working fork pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".maindiv").hover(function () {
        $(this).find('#more').css("display","block");
    },function() {
  $(this).find('#more').css("display","none");
});
```

A working fiddle: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/effone/Kg2wV/)

You can even use show(); / hide();

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for JQuery to implement this, simply add to your css:

```
div.maindiv div#more {
    display: none;
}

div.maindiv:hover div#more {
    display: block;
}
```

However it'll occupy space when shown. You can consider using opacity instead of display to avoid this.

Comment: thank you , first thing i have tried!

Comment: This is the way it should be done actually, but I've posted my solution based on what OP is following. But I will still suggest doing this way only.